# Unable to start Acitivity on miui9

Tags: android, crash, miui

I'm new to Android and currently I have a thorny problem.
My application is crashed on MIUI9(Android 7.1.1), but it's working good on other device(Android N). I don't know how did it happend.
Below is the log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.*****.***.***/com.*****.***.***.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Thread android.os.Looper.getThread()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2740)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2801)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1548)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6365)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:791)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Thread android.os.Looper.getThread()' on a null object reference
    at miui.util.AttributeResolver.bR(SourceFile:35)
    at miui.util.AttributeResolver.resolveInt(SourceFile:145)
    at miui.util.AttributeResolver.isUsingMiuiTheme(SourceFile:179)
    at miui.os.Environment.isUsingMiui(SourceFile:108)
    at android.view.ViewConfigurationInjector.get(ViewConfigurationInjector.java:18)
    at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:369)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4028)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4154)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:579)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:575)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:571)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:567)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:78)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.<init>(DecorView.java:237)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2283)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2621)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2049)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:371)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:320)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:272)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:148)
    at cn.droidlover.xdroidmvp.mvp.XActivity.onCreate(XActivity.java:42)
    at com.*****.***.***.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:48)
    at com.*****.***.***.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:49)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6861)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
```

Comment: Clean the project, rebuild it & try again. If not, it's better if you could give more details of your app which will help the community to pinpoint your issue.

Comment: @RamithDR Thank you very much. I've tried, but it doesn't work. I think that's MIUI9's problem. I'll contact XiaoMi to find some help.

Comment: Share your code for more details and also read MIUI9(Android 7.1.1) changes logs.